# how to avoid removing 0 from msb in python panda dataframe

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

i have data in column  like `0123456789` after reading from a file it will get like `123456789` where column name is `msisdn`

how to fix this issue

am using the pandas script as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
import gc
import pandas
csv1 = pandas.read_csv('/home/subin/Desktop/a.txt')
csv2 = pandas.read_csv('/home/subin/Desktop/b.txt')
merged = pandas.merge(csv1, csv2,left_on=['MSISDN'],right_on=['MSISDN'],how='left',suffixes=('#x', '#y'), sort=True).fillna('0')
merged.to_csv("/home/subin/Desktop/amergeb_out.txt", index=False, float_format='%.0f')
```

Comment: Why would you want to avoid dumping the MSB of 0? That's completely irrelevant to a number. If you're trying to save an ID or something that does somehow rely on the 0, then you should be reading in your data as a string anyways, as it's not a number in that case.

Comment: @ Ricky Mutschlechner    its  number i cant remove 0 from MSB any chance?

Answer (score 1):

You can cast column `msisdn` to `string` by parameter `dtype` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
temp=u"""msisdn
0123456789
0123456789"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), dtype={'msisdn': str})
print (df)
       msisdn
0  0123456789
1  0123456789
```

Comment: I think it is impossible convert it to `integer` number, if first digit is `0`. There is problem with `merge`, so do you need number?

Answer (score 0):

```
csv1 = pandas.read_csv('/home/subin/Desktop/a.txt',dtype=str)
csv2 = pandas.read_csv('/home/subin/Desktop/b.txt',dtype={'MSISDN': str})
merged = pandas.merge(csv1, csv2,left_on=['MSISDN'],right_on=['MSISDN'],how='left',suffixes=('#x', '#y'), sort=True).fillna('0')
merged.to_csv("/home/subin/Desktop/amergeb_out.txt", index=False, float_format='%.0f')
```